# Streaming video file through flash player

Tags: video, flash, mp4, avi

Well, I am not really sure what are the tags applicable for this thread. I would like to show video files (mp4, avi) in my website but no one should be able to download (unlike youtube, dailymotion, because there are downloaders to download video from these). We can compare this to some online movie watching stuff. My idea is streaming the video file into flv player (actually this is not my portfolio and I am a Java developer ). I would appreciate any idea and advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when streaming over HTTP you are unable to completely restrict access to file that is streamed with FlashPlayer.

There is simple reason for this FlashPlayer is a plugin and every time you make HTTP request (to load video) from it, it goes over browser, so user can easily get details about the request. When you are loading video request method is GET and one can use it's query string to download video.

Adobe **Flash Media Server** can be solution to this, it can stream over RTMP and in this case users cannot use browser or other programs to download video over HTTP as it is done in case www.youtube.com

I think you should also take a look at [Wowza Media Server](http://www.wowza.com)

Both of above servers are commercials so, maybe best option will be this open source streaming server [RED5](http://www.red5.org/)